# Meaning of "... relieved me of my artisanal meat platter"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> Nick Dunne: *It could. I mean, the Amish are on a rumspringa.*
>   [Amy looks across the room at the three Amish looking men and chuckles]
>   Amy Dunne: ***They already relieved me of my artisanal meat platter.***
>   Nick Dunne: *Finally, someone tells me how to pronounce that word*.
>   Amy Dunne: *“Meat”?*
>
> <sub>From the movie [*Gone Girl*](http://www.moviequotesandmore.com/gone-girl-quotes/)</sub>

Does the sentence in bold mean she received compliments on the dish she made?

My research:

- *relieved* means feeling happy.
- *artisanal* means some skills where something is made especially by hand.
- *platter* means a large plate for serving food.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51052/discussion-on-question-by-sunman-meaning-of-they-already-relieved-me-of-my-arti).

Comment: It's always a good idea to repeat the actual question within the body, and to provide context, i.e. the phrases before and after the quote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means they took a large plate of fancy meat away from the speaker.

To be relieved is to be unburdened by something. If you had to carry a rock up a mountain and someone "relieved you" of your burden, it would mean they took your burden away. In this case the speaker is saying that someone took the burden of the large plate of meats away.

Artisanal: means a skilled worker produced the meats with care and attention to detail.

Platter is a large (usually formal) serving plate. You do not eat off of these plates, they are only for presenting food, to eat you must remove food from the platter and put it on your plate.